# Not able to send emails through send grid when i add cc and bcc

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, sendgrid

I am try to send email notification with to list, cc list and bcc list but I am getting error says bad request and success code as false.

If I don't add cc, bcc list, I am able to send email. Can you please help me on this

var apiKey = "SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
var msg = new SendGridMessage();

```
        msg.From = new EmailAddress("xxxxxx@nidec-motor.com", "TechM");
        msg.Subject = "Test email";
        msg.PlainTextContent = "Sendgrid test email";
        msg.HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello World!";
        msg.Personalizations = new List<Personalization>
            {
            new Personalization
            {
                  Tos = new List<EmailAddress>
                  {
                       new EmailAddress("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "Eswar"),
                       new EmailAddress("xxxx@techmahindra.com", "Test User-Eswar")
                  },
                  Ccs= new List<EmailAddress>()
                  {
                         new EmailAddress("xxxx@TechMahindra.com", "Eswar"),
                       new EmailAddress("xxxx@techmahindra.com", "Test User-Eswar") 
                  },
                  Bccs=new List<EmailAddress>()
                  {
                         new EmailAddress("xxx@gmail.com", "Eswar"),
                       new EmailAddress("xxx@techmahindra.com", "Test User-Eswar")
                  }
            }

        };

        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        var test = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you pass empty List at Ccs like: `Ccs= new List<EmailAddress>()` ?

Comment: The question here is, Why I am not able to send email with cc list and bcc list? if  I remove cc, bcc lists it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

sendgrid doesn't send emails when any of the three are missing like `to, cc, bcc`. Either, you have to include all three inorder to work or eliminate keys from the `Email List`.

For example: This is how I would do it in the `JS`, where `to`, `bcc` and `cc` keys will gets added only when it has some data given.

```
const sendEmailObj = {
      from: `goutham`,
      ...(to !== '' && {to: to?.split(',')}),
      ...(ccEmailAddress !== '' && {cc: ccEmailAddress?.split(',')}),
      ...(bccEmailAddress !== '' && {bcc: bccEmailAddress?.split(',')}),
      template: 'temaplate-id',
      subject: `Sendgrid Working`,
      context: {
        message: 'Hello world!'
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue with Sendgrid. Sendgrid won't allow duplicate Email addresses in To,CC, BCC Blocks.

Error message I got:

> Each unique email address in the personalizations array should only be included once. You have included [email address] more than once.

**SendGrid Docs**

https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/errors#personalizationsbcc